# Como traduzir o termo "ticket"?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, tradução

Não é bem uma tradução, porque parece que todos os sistemas já incorporaram a palavra. Mas, basicamente, eu quero um termo da língua portuguesa para "support ticket", que é comum em sistemas de atendimento.

Quando um cliente ou usuário precisa enviar uma dúvida, reclamação, sugestão, crítica ou requisição de atendimento, ele abre um "ticket", descreve o que ele deseja e recebe um número que ele pode usar para acompanhar o status. O "ticket" recebe um status de "aguardando" até que alguém atenda o ticket e entre em contato com o cliente.

Acredito que, no inglês, seja uma metáfora com filas de atendimento, já que nelas, geralmente, os clientes pegam um bilhete com a senha de atendimento e aguardam serem chamados. Mas não quero usar o termo "bilhete" porque não lhes é familiar.

De que eu posso chamar este "objeto" de uma forma clara e concisa?

Comment: abre um chamado

Comment: Ramon, explica-me lá melhor isso do "pegam um bilhete com a senha de atendimento": eles trocam uma senha por um bilhete?! Ou é "bilhete como senha"?

Comment: @Jacinto No bilhete vem escrito uma senha. Daí, acredito eu, que vem o termo "ticket", porque a senha de atendimento vem escrita num bilhete. Mas é tudo metafórico, o sistema não imprime nenhum bilhete propriamente dito.

Comment: Ah, *senha* é um número ou coisa assim que identifica o teu pedido? É que nós aqui já confundimos *senha* com o próprio bilhete. Por exemplo, chegas a uma farmácia e "tiras uma senha" (um papelinho com o teu número de atendimento).

Comment: Sim, tudo metafórico: eu já abri vários *tickets* lá na universidade; depois o pessoal da informática resolve o assunto ou contacta-me.

Comment: @Jacinto Aqui também é assim, estava só explicando o porquê do "ticket"  mesmo. Às vezes, também chamamos de "número", mas é a mesma metonímia.

Comment: @AndréLyra "chamado" não é ruim, até posso usá-la. Mas queria um novo termo, porque nem todos os tickets exigem minha atenção. Alguns estão ali só para "ciência", não tem ninguém realmente me chamando.

Comment: Olha, o meu carro empanou, telefonei à Assistência em Viagem, e eles criaram-me um "dossier" com um número. Bem, isto é um ticket, não?

Comment: @Jacinto espero que estejas em segurança (não sei o que _empanar_ significa). Dossiê, por aqui, é um arquivo que lista provas documentais e registros históricos. Muito popular em campanhas eleitorais.

Comment: Vê no Priberam. Nada, cheguei lá de manhã e o carro estava "morto". Mesmo com ligação à bateria de outro carro, rodo a chave na ignição, e nada, nem um pio. Mas o que a Assistência fez foi abrir um ticket, não? Conjunto de informações sobre o meu problema, com um número a identificar a coisa toda. Mas chamaram-lhe *dossier* (ou *dossiê*); neste sentido é mais ou menos sinónimo de *pasta*.

Comment: Só conhecia este significado aqui: _[Brasil]   [Culinária]  Passar por ovo batido e cobrir de pão ralado ou de farinha de trigo para depois fritar. = PANAR_. Sim, ela abriu um ticket, mas, além dele, a assistência necessita da documentação para enviar à seguradora.

Comment: Era a *Assistência* da minha seguradora.

Comment: Tendo visto com mais atenção a tua resposta, foi assim mesmo que eu interpretei *dossiê*: uma pasta ou arquivo em que são reunidos todos os documentos relativos ao meu caso, desde o meu pedido de assistência com os dados do problema, registos de todas as diligências para efetuadas, até ao encerramento do caso.

Answer (score 10):

No caso de sistemas de atendimento, call centers e similares, ouço muito usarem o próprio termo *ticket* mesmo. Mas também já vi muitos usarem **requisição**, **chamado** e **número de protocolo** (sendo que este último é muitas vezes chamado apenas de **protocolo**, ou mais formalmente de **protocolo de atendimento**)

Pelo que vi em vários sistemas, os termos mais comuns são *ticket* e **protocolo**, sendo este último mais usado na comunicação com o usuário (toda vez que ligo para um call center pedem para anotar o número do protocolo)

A única exceção que me lembro são as seguradoras, que chamam os seus *tickets* de **sinistros**.

Comment: Solicitação de atendimento já foi mais conhecida por Chamado (priberam: pedido de ajuda). Ultimamente passaram a chamar apenas de protocolo mesmo, pois as pessoas tem de anotar protocolos de atendimento dos chamados do telemarketing.

Comment: +1 pelo _protocolo_. Não tem nenhuma conotação negativa (já que o "ticket" pode ser só uma sugestão), e também não indica que eu vou responder (alguns "tickets" são só para registro histórico). Parece um termo bem claro para quem está lendo. Meu único receio é que seja um pouco formal demais. Farei um teste por alguns dias, se "pegar", vou aceitar.

Comment: @RamonMelo Em sistemas de suporte técnico (de TI), "chamado" é bem comum, pelo menos nos sistemas que eu já vi.

Comment: @bfavaretto Com certeza o é, mas o sistema de que estou falando não é voltado a suporte técnico, era só um exemplo mesmo.

Comment: Em Portugal, "chamado" não faz sentido. Só percebo pelo contexto. Uma "chamada" seria uma chamada telefónica, um chamado não percebo bem o que seria. Algo relacionado com chamar...?

Comment: @ANeves Segundo o [priberam](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/chamado) chamado = apelo. A palavra chamado com este sentido é mais usado no mundo da politica se nao me engano.

Comment: @ANeves, o que eu vejo muito são empresas usando o termo "chamado" internamente, principalmente para suporte de microinformática (se o teclado parou de funcionar, por exemplo, eu abro um "chamado" para o suporte - neste caso, tem mais ou menos o mesmo sentido de _ticket_, requisição, solicitação, protocolo...)

Comment: Sim, obrigado, faz todo o sentido. Só é uma palavra que desconheço. :)

Answer (score 4):

Tendo sido funcionário público, mormente técnico superior, e considerando uma linguagem mais formal, tendo em consideração que estamos perante um pedido de suporte ou ajuda, o termo apropriado no meu entender seria:

> requerimento

àquele que faz o pedido de ajuda, denomina-se de

> requerente

É esse o termo usado na Administração Pública em Portugal, e estou em crer, também no Brasil.

Answer (score 3):

Um ticket, em inglês muitas vezes também conhecido como `case` ou `issue`, pode ser traduzido como:

> Questão (de suporte)

Esta é a [primeira sugestão de tradução do google para Issue](https://translate.google.com/#en/pt/issue)

Se não gosta da palavra, ou não a considera adequada, já que ela pode implicar que o cliente tem uma dúvida e não um problema, encontrou nesta frase a sua resposta. Uma questão é também um problema.

> Problema (de suporte)

Por último `support ticket` tem como [única tradução no google](https://translate.google.com/#en/pt/support%20ticket)

> Ticket de suporte

Ticket é eventualmente uma palavra comum em ambiente de trabalho que deve ser entendida pelo menos pela equipa de suporte, não vejo motivos para não ser usada.

A palavra pendente associada a uma destas traduções também pode ajudar, mas tenha atenção que ao usá-la está a excluir todos os *tickets* resolvidos. O uso de pendente já cai melhor também com a palavra caso (na minha opinião). `Caso pendente` (que eu não sugeri anteriormente).

Comment: Interessante, o nome do módulo é "issue" (o "ticket" é um objeto dentro do "issue", mas não quero entrar em detalhes de implementação). Um "issue" (que eu traduzi como "assunto") pode ter vários "tickets", relacionados ou não. Eu posso, de fato, usar "ticket" e creio que todos entenderiam. Mas gostaria de evitar os anglicismos, se possível.

Comment: "Problema" também não encaixa, porque pode ser só uma sugestão. "Questão" se alinha mais com o que eu estou procurando, por ser um termo mais amplo.

Answer (score 2):

Algumas traduções para *ticket*, vai depender do contexto:

- Bilhete
- Protocolo

No seu caso se aplica melhor protocolo, como "protocolo de atendimento", ou até mesmo "protocolo de suporte" (já vi usarem esse também).

Um outro exemplo é a traducão de "***issue ticket***", que embora possa ser "protocolo de ocorrência", no Brasil é mais comum também ser "protocolo de atendimento", mesmo que o atendimento nem tenha iniciado e seja apenas um relato de problema.

Ligue para qualquer central de atendimento de empresas no Brasil, como operadoras de telefonia, bancos, cartões de crédito, fornecedoras de sinais de TV, internet, água, gás, luz, etc. É bem provável que todos façam uso do termo "Protocolo de atendimento", e em alguns talvez você consiga o seu protocolo mesmo antes de se identificar como cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Bem você tem várias maneiras de traduzir **ticket** dependendo da frase contextual:

Ticket de alimentação = Vale/Cartão
Ticket = Ingresso
Ticket de support = Algo como bilhete, senha de suporte.

Enfim, depende da frase, mas no caso de **ticket de suporte** creio que o mais correto seria *Bilhete de Suporte* que no caso você teria um requerimento de suporte e estaria aguardando o suporte, então você tem um bilhete.